# Binding SSL Cert to Port Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
 $Thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match "CN=appserver.domain.com"}).Thumbprint;

    $guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
    $certHash = $thumbprint
    $ip = "0.0.0.0" # This means all IP addresses
    $port = "8280" # the default HTTPS port

    "http add sslcert ipport=$($ip):$port certhash=$Thumbprint appid={$guid}" | netsh
```

I got this from a search online, but it doesn't work. The entry isn't created when I run it. I'm checking with `netsh http show sslcert` and nothing is there.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you run the code? I assume you are replacing `appserver.domain.com` with your actual certificate name?

Comment: Nothing - the thumbprint is stored in the variable but the Netsh command wont work as, surely you cant pipe it to the command - no & operator is used either. I've searched on this extensively and cannot get netsh working in Powershell at all like i can with other exe's. Odd, hopefully somebody can help

Comment: Correct, in answer to your question James C. Thanks

Comment: PS C:\Windows\System32> Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {& C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe {"http add sslcert ipport=$($ip):$port certhash=$Thumbprint appid={$guid}"}}
The following command was not found: -noninteractive -encodedCommand IgBoAHQAdABwACAAYQBkAGQAIABzAHMAbABjAGUAcgB0ACAAaQBwAHAAbwByAHQAPQAkACgAJABpAHAAKQA6ACQAcABvAHIAdAAgAGMAZQByAHQAaABhAHMAaAA9ACQAVABoAHUAbQBiAHAAcgBpAG4AdAAgAGEAcABwAGkAZAA9AHsAJABnAHUAaQBk
AH0AIgA= -inputFormat xml -out....

Comment: @Royston same issue here. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

If you have PowerShell 4.0+ you can use Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding

Docs + Example https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/networktransition/add-netiphttpscertbinding

Comment: This does not work on Windows 7, even with PowerShell 5.1 installed

Answer (score 0):

Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding does not work on Windows 7, but this did:

```
$params_add = "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$Thumbprint appid={aedae042-2b80-475d-861b-8f8c5d876098}"
cmd.exe /c $params_add --%
```